# How to change property in Redux Toolkit

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I need to select `productItem` from the Redux state and change the property. When I click the `Mark All` button I want to be selected all items in `li`.

**productSlice.js**

```
    const productSlice = createSlice({
  name: "product",
  initialState: [],
  reducers: {
    addProduct: (state, action) => {
      const productItem = {
        id: nanoid(),
        title: action.payload.title,
        isComplete: false,
      };
      state.push(productItem);
    },
    toggleComplete: (state, action) => {
      const idx = state.findIndex(
        (product) => product.id === action.payload.id
      );
      state[idx].isComplete = action.payload.isComplete;
    },
  },
});

export const { addProduct, toggleComplete } = productSlice.actions;

export default productSlice.reducer;
```

**ProductList.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import ProductItem from "./ProductItem";
import { Form } from "react-bootstrap";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";

import "./ProductList.css";
import { toggleComplete } from "../redux/productSlice";

function ProductList({ id, isComplete }) {
  const productItem = useSelector((state) => state.product);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  function handleMarkAll() {
    dispatch(
      toggleComplete({
        id: id,
        isComplete: !isComplete,
      })
    );
  }

  return (
    <ul className="productUl">
      <Form.Check label="Mark All" onChange={handleMarkAll} />

      {productItem.map((product, idx) => (
        <ProductItem
          key={idx}
          id={product.id}
          title={product.title}
          isComplete={product.isComplete}
        />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}

export default ProductList;
```

When `Mark All` button is clicked, want to change `productItem.isComplete` to `!isComplete`

Comment: Could you state your specific problem?

Comment: My specific problem is when I click Form.Check labeled “Mark All” I need to change state property of state item, called ‘isComplete’

Comment: "Mark ALL" should change the redux state of a SINGLE item?

Comment: Need to change property of all items in state

Comment: Then will need to create another action for that. Maybe toggleAllComplete(). Then remap every items in the store.